# Rasa Integration with mongdb

Tags: chatbot, rasa, rasa-nlu

Who can help me fix my error, when I test my chatbot

```
Your input → hello
Hey! How are you? Your input → I want a GYM Title
C:\Users\\OneDrive\Bureau\pfa\chatbotEnv\lib\site-packages\rasa\shared\utils\io.py:99: UserWarning: Parsed an entity ‘resources_type’ which is not defined in the domain. Please make sure all entities are listed in the domain. More info at Domain
```

I expect it to respond from the dataset

Comment: Please check the link below. This might be similar issue.  Otherwise please share your domain and nlu file if possible.

https://forum.rasa.com/t/userwarning-interpreter-parsed-an-entity-user-name-which-is-not-defined-in-the-domain-please-make-sure-all-entities-are-listed-in-the-domain/36924